# Resizing TinyMCE in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, tinymce, django-widget

I am trying to write a widget to resize my django tinymce but it doesn't seem to work...

Does anyone know what the problem is with this code snippet?

```py
from django import forms 
from .models import blog, comment, reply, like, subscription
from tinymce.widgets import TinyMCE

class blogform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = blog
        fields  = ['content', 'title', 'blog_pic']
        widgets = {'content': (TinyMCE(attrs={'style':'height:100vh; width:60%'}))}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was;I had an app.js file in my static folder that had a configuration to style the tinymce editor; all i had to do was change the width or height to fit my needs...this is the code

```
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea",      
        height: "700",
        width: "60%",
        plugins: "insertdatetime media image preview",
        toolbar: "undo redo |  bold italic | alignleft alignright                           aligncenter alignjustify | image media | preview",
        image_title: true,
image_caption: true,
automatic_uploads: true,
image_advtab: true,
file_picker_types: "image media",

file_picker_callback: function (cb, value, meta) {
  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.setAttribute("type", "file");
  if (meta.filetype == "image") {
      input.setAttribute("accept", "image/*");}
  if (meta.filetype == "media") {
  input.setAttribute("accept", "video/*");}

  input.onchange = function () {     
      var file = this.files[0];
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function () {
          var id = "blobid" + (new Date()).getTime();
          var blobCache =  tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
          var base64 = reader.result.split(",")[1];
          var blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file, base64);
          blobCache.add(blobInfo);
         cb(blobInfo.blobUri(), { title: file.name });
       };
       reader.readAsDataURL(file);
   };
   input.click();
},
content_style: "body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px }"});
```

Comment: If you think you solves your problem, please  improve your solution and mark it as the answer

Comment: Merci...I'll do an edit later on